# Chart.js 4.4.2, how to have mutiple datapoints/labels in the tooltips when hovering over a datapoint?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

As the title explains, I am trying to create a report using chart.js to give the user a graphical representation of the data that they have searched for in the system, I am currently able to get the data to display on the canvas.

I have the data being provided to the JS function in a JSON format from the backend of the system. I have the main data that is building the pie chart with other data needing to be added to the tooltips to give further explanation on that data point.

How would I go about this as looking online hasn't given any viable result that has worked?

I have attached a simplified version of the code below with the data being displayed and how it is produced in the system.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var data = {
  title: "Booking duration between 01/08/2023 and 29/03/2024",
  labels: ["0 - 6 days", "7 - 13 days", "14 - 20 days", "21 - 27 days", "28 - 34 days"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [2126, 430, 51, 20, 44],
    backgroundColor: ["#82B6EB", "#434348", "#94EE7E", "#F3A15E", "#8385E8"],
    datalabels: ["79.6 %", "16.1 %", "1.91 %", "0.75 %", "1.65 %"],
    databooking: ["( 2126 bookings)", "( 430 bookings)", "( 51 bookings)", "( 20 bookings)", "( 44 bookings)"],
    hoverOffset: 20
  }]
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: data,
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, chartData) {
          var dataset = chartData.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
          var dataLabel = dataset.datalabels[tooltipItem.index];
          var dataBooking = dataset.databooking[tooltipItem.index];
          return 'Value: ' + currentValue + ' ' + dataLabel + ' ' + dataBooking;
        },
        title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
          return data.title;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="_Chart">
  <canvas id="myChart" style="width:1700px; max-height: 550px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that with Chart.js v4, the [`tooltip` configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration) needs to be placed inside `options.plugins`. The context passed to the tooltip `callbacks` is described [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-item-context).

Your `callbacks` could be written as follows:

```
callbacks: {
  label: ctx => 'Value: ' + ctx.raw + ' ' + ctx.label + ' ' + ctx.dataset.databooking[ctx.dataIndex],
  title: ctx => data.title
}
```

Please take a look at your amended code below and see how it works.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var data = {
  title: "Booking duration between 01/08/2023 and 29/03/2024",
  labels: ["0 - 6 days", "7 - 13 days", "14 - 20 days", "21 - 27 days", "28 - 34 days"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [2126, 430, 51, 20, 44],
    backgroundColor: ["#82B6EB", "#434348", "#94EE7E", "#F3A15E", "#8385E8"],
    datalabels: ["79.6 %", "16.1 %", "1.91 %", "0.75 %", "1.65 %"],
    databooking: ["( 2126 bookings)", "( 430 bookings)", "( 51 bookings)", "( 20 bookings)", "( 44 bookings)"],
    hoverOffset: 20
  }]
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: ctx => 'Value: ' + ctx.raw + ' ' + ctx.label + ' ' + ctx.dataset.databooking[ctx.dataIndex],
          title: ctx => data.title
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" style="max-height: 200px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on this, I have this working as needed in the system.